# How do make username and email field validations

Tags: django

I am trying to check if email already exists in the database during signup but with the below code I am not getting it

```
forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from . models import registration_form

class signup_form(ModelForm):
    Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    Confirm_pwd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = registration_form
        fields=['Firstname','Lastname','Username','Email','Password','Confirm_pwd']
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(signup_form, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("Password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("Confirm_pwd")
        print(confirm_password)

        if password != confirm_password:
            print("yes")
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "password and confirm_password does not match"
                )   

    def clean_Email(self):
        Email = self.cleaned_data.get('Email')
        try:
          match = registration_form.objects.get(Email=Email)
          print(match)
        except registration_form.DoesNotExist:
        # Unable to find a user, this is fine
          return Email
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')
```

It is throwing an error as
`MultipleObjectsReturned at /form/
get() returned more than one registration_form -- it returned 10`!

Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `registration_form` model isn't set to `unique=True` on the `Email` field and your dataset has more than one `registration_form` object with the provided value.  You'll want to handle `MultipleObjectsReturned`.
Another recommendation would be to perform the filter with case insensitivity:

```
match = registration_form.objects.get(Email__iexact=Email)
```

Ultimately, you could handle the duplicate entries with a migration, make the `registration_form.Email` field `unique=True` and perform a `.get` while handling the `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception:

```
def clean_Email(self):
    Email = self.cleaned_data.get('Email')
    try:
      match = registration_form.objects.get(Email__iexact=Email)
      print(match)
    except registration_form.DoesNotExist:
      # Unable to find a user, this is fine
      return Email
    except registration_form.MultipleObjectsReturned:
      # Pass here to hit the validation error
      pass
    raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')
```

You could simply adjust your query to check: `registration_form.objects.filter(Email__iexact=Email).exists()`

```
def clean_Email(self):
    Email = self.cleaned_data.get('Email')
    match = registration_form.objects.filter(Email__iexact=Email).exists()

    if match:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')
    return Email
```